# Joining bones disappear

Tags: rigging, bones

[image]

I tried too Ctrl+J these bones too my rig but when i do they just disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your destination rig has bone layer n. 00 off, so they are there but they are hidden to the view.

Another possibility is that the two rigs had different scale, so that as they are joined the new bones change their scale: always apply all transform (Ctrl A) before joining.

Another possibility is that the joined rig was parented to something with a transform on it, so when it gets joined it looses the transform and it changes loc and/or rot and/or scale (Alt P keep transform before joining).

Check the outliner for clear understanding of where the joined bones went.